# Joda DateTime format to yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

This is the DateTime format that am getting using Joda DateTime `2019-01-10T13:59:36.700+05:30`

```
 claimGroupingHistory.setCreatedAt(new DateTime());
```

But am getting the below error while inserting into the DB

```
2019-01-10 13:59:36,754 [http-9292-1] ERROR   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: 146 - Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x16org.joda.time.DateTime\xB8<xdj[\xDD\xF9\x02\x00\x00xr\x00\x1Forg.joda.time.base.BaseDateTime\xFF\xFF\x' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

How i can format Joda DateTime into `yyyy-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` this format to insert into the DB

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.joda.org/joda-time-hibernate/userguide.html

Comment: You shouldn't. You should be storing the "value" in a standard date/time into the database and letting the driver deal with the conversion

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should use for  Hibernate 3:

```
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
```

on the field

And for  Hibernate version 4-5 add the following:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
```

http://jadira.sourceforge.net/

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time-hibernate